# Citation help in APA format

Tags: citations

I'm not sure if this question belongs here - if not please redirect me to the right place. I want to cite http://www.act.org/content/dam/act/unsecured/documents/cccr2018/National-CCCR-2018.pdf in APA format, but I'm not sure how to do it. I don't understand how to classify it. Can anyone help me?
If this question does not belong here, can you redirect me to the proper place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APA follows the basic format of [Who-When-What-Where](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/basic-principles). In your case, it will be:

`ACT. (2018, October 18). Condition of College and Career Readiness 2018. http://www.act.org/content/act/en/research/reports/act-publications/condition-of-college-and-career-readiness-2018.html`

Some details:

- **Who?** There is no individual author named; we shall thus take the authoring organization, *ACT*.
- **When?** The report is from [18 October 2018](http://www.act.org/content/act/en/research/reports/act-publications/condition-of-college-and-career-readiness-2018.html); use the format [YYYY, Month Day](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/elements-list-entry#date) for the publication type 'report'.
- **What?** The title of the report (*Condition of College and Career Readiness 2018*).
- **Where?** The URL where the report can be retrieved from. (Note: The additional words "Retrieved from [URL]" used to be mandatory [in earlier versions of the APA Style Guide](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2014/02/how-to-cite-an-annual-report-in-apa-style.html), but not in the current version anymore - [see, for example, here](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/report-government-agency-references).)

Comment: You mention that the words retrieved from are no longer mandatory. Does this mean thye are optional or that they are no longer supposed to be there?

Comment: See APA Style Guide 9.16: If the source's content is likely to change over time, then you can add "Retrieved from"; otherwise it is better to archive the webpage you cite, in which case no "Retrieved from" is required anymore.

Comment: So if I'm not sure, and I just write retrieved from, it is okay.